# Преобразовать Timestamp в дату

Tags: java, дата, timestamp

В БД хранится timestamp, хочу преобразовать его в дату, но почему-то выводится дата понедельник 19 января 1970 года. Что я не так делаю?

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(1580677200);
System.out.println(new Date(timestamp.getTime()));
```

Хотя это timestamp 03.02.2020

Answer (score 1):

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(1580677200L);
```

Comment: Разобрался, нужно было сделать * 1000L

Answer (score 1):

Пример конвертирования секунд в дату, используя [Instant.ofEpochSecond](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-) и [Timestamp.from](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#from-java.time.Instant-):

```
Instant now = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1580677200);
System.out.println(now); // 2020-02-02T21:00:00Z

Timestamp current = Timestamp.from(now);
System.out.println(current); // 2020-02-03 02:00:00.0
```